# Deploying a VB.net 2010 Win Forms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, installation

I am deploying a VB.net 2010 winforms application, and when I install it on the client's machine, the install process also installs an instance of SQL Server 2005 Express. The application connects to a central SQL database on the server. To install, I am using the "Publish" option in VS 2010

Why does it do that? There should be no need for a local instance of SQL Express. Is there a way to avoid installing SQL 2005 Express (I know it is free, but I would rather not have it installed if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that whatever technology you're using for packaging/deployment is including the installer for SQL.  For the default setup project, I believe it is a checkbox for a pre-requisite.

Comment: I am using the "Publish" option in VS 2010. I don't recall seeing a checkbox to prevent the install.

Comment: Select the application (exe) project in your solution and open the "Properties" page. Select the "Publish" tab. Under the "Install Mode and Settings" section is a Prerequisites button. That should bring them up.